# Extending WooCommerce class triggers Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Coupon' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to extend WooCommerce class WC_Coupon in my plugin like this:

```
class Email_Coupon extends \WC_Coupon 
{
}
```

but I am getting an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Coupon' not found in /var/www/vhosts/....../models/Email_Coupon.php:4
```

WooCommerce is installed and enabled. I found out that a third party plugin uses the same declaration when installed and does not trigger such error. Do I need to somehow import woocommerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your class inside a hook where WooCommerce has been already initialized, for example the `init` hook.

```
function register_email_coupon_class()
{
    class Email_Coupon extends \WC_Coupon 
    {
    }
}
add_action('init', 'register_email_coupon_class');
```